# In R, how to "read" an image (bmp ou png) in windows clipboard

Tags: r, windows, image, clipboard

Is there a way to read the windows clipboard in order to transfer an image (bmp or png) that is in the clipboard to an R variable ?
I try several things like readClipboard(format=2, raw=TRUE) after checking the type of the clipboard data with getClipboardFormats()
but i only obtain a NULL value !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In fact, my script in intended to analyse what the PC user is doing. So, it take screenshoot regularly, using an external soft "boxcutter".

Comment: So I use system(paste('".\\doc_boxcutter\\boxcutter.exe"', xy, paste(dir_screenshot, filename, sep="\\")), wait = FALSE) and after that, to get the image, I am obliged to do use image_read(paste(dir_screenshot, filename, sep="\\")).

Comment: In order to avoid writing and reading on the hard drive many many times a file which is used only once, I am wondering if it is possible to use the system clipboard in order to obtain the screenshots i need. Something like sending "Windows Key + PrtScn" followed by "readClipboard(...) ?